# Ошибка при входе по ssl

Tags: nginx, zabbix

Настраиваю ssl на сайте но после настроек получаю ошибку ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Ubuntu 22.04 nginx 1.18.0
@zabbix.conf

```html
server { 
        #listen         10.52.2.91:80;
         listen         10.52.2.91:443;
         server_name    zabbix6.my.domain;
         ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my.domain;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my.domain.key;
                  
        
        root    /usr/share/zabbix;

        index   index.php;
       
        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found   off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /assets {
                access_log      off;
                expires         10d;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny            all;
        }

        location ~ /(api\/|conf[^\.]|include|locale) {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location /vendor {
                deny            all;
                return          404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/zabbix.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;

                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/share/zabbix;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE    $content_type;
                fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH  $content_length;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
                fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
                fastcgi_buffers                 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       256k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
        }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```html
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    
     listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
         server_name    zabbix6.mc.bank;
         ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mc_bank.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mc.bank.key;

    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/zabbix/nginx.conf

```html
server {
    listen          10.52.2.91:443;
        server_name     zabbix6.my.domain;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Обычно под этой ошибкой есть блок с подробностями. В чём собственно ошибка.

Comment: В firefox При соединении с zabbix6.my.domain произошла ошибка. SSL получило запись, длина которой превышает максимально допустимую.

Код ошибки: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG                                                                                    В edge Подключение к этому сайту не защищеноС сайта zabbix6.my.domaain отправлен недопустимый отклик.
Попробуйте выполнить диагностику сети Windows
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: `listen         10.52.2.91:443;` — вы забыли включить ssl вот здесь

Comment: (и кстати http2 тоже стоит включить, в 2023 году живём всё-таки)

Comment: listen         10.52.2.91:443 ssl; так? (и кстати http2 тоже стоит включить, в 2023 году живём всё-таки)  и как его включить?